# No resource identifier found for attribute 'cacheColorHint' in package

Tags: android

I'm trying to use this two-way-grid-view lib:

https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

My xml file:

[image]

My project is running well before I clone it to different path, package...

Actually it shows error on all properties "app:....".

Can anyone suggest me something about this error, I'm wasting more hours about this.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you move com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView to you own project or complie it?

Comment: I try 2 ways: (1) Build the lib project and get jar file and push into my project. (2) Add the lib project as my project's library. Still catching the errors.

Comment: Try to search cacheColorHint in your project

Comment: Plz  upload screenshot of  you library project

Answer (score 2):

Try to search cacheColorHint in your old project.

likely:

```
<declare-styleable name="TwoWayGridView">
    <attr name="cacheColorHint" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: oh man, you're god, damn that!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I copy att.xml file from the lib project into my project and its clean :).